# Synergy client drops when installing something

Tags: windows-7, windows, installation, user-accounts, synergy

Synergy client PC drops connection when I try to install a new program.  Windows creates that standard popup saying:

> Do you want to allow the following program from an unknown publisher to make changes to this computer?

At which point, Synergy is dropped.

What's going on?

OS is Windows 7.

Comment: You have to run the client as administrator. This solves your problem - at least it solved mine.

Answer (score 3):

This is because when that UAC dialog appears, Windows prevents most programs from controlling the mouse and keyboard, to prevent a malicious application from clicking the "Yes" button on your behalf. The whole point is that it must be YOU to authorize the app.

You could try running the Synergy program as an administrator. I'm not sure if that will work but it's worth a try. Failing that, you'll simply need to turn UAC off.

Comment: I highly recommend not turning UAC off. I had the same problem and used this page: http://n00tz.net/2010/01/quick-tip-synergy-on-windows-7/ to setup the system to not have conflicts with synergy and UAC. It works perfectly for me.

Comment: MaQleod's link is dead, but archived: http://wayback.archive.org/web/20120414151331/http://n00tz.net/2010/01/quick-tip-synergy-on-windows-7 (looks like it shows you how to run synergy as admin).